# How to save a plot made with ggplot2 as SVG

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I want to save a stacked area plot (Plot example with code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196529/how-to-name-sections-on-x-axis-that-are-seperated-by-vertical-lines-in-an-r-plot)) made with **ggplot2** as **SVG**. Tried it with the **Cairo package** but the outcome is bad.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(Cairo)
...

#png(output_file, width=800, height=400)
Cairo(800,400,file=paste(output_file, ".svg", sep=""),type="svg",bg="transparent",pointsize=8, units="px",dpi=400)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)

dev.off()
```

Comment: There is the CRAN package [RSvgDevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSvgDevice/index.html), but you depending on your system you have to build from source.

Comment: High resolution png's look really good actually, `ggsave` can be used for that.

Comment: The `svg` device in the `grGraphics` package comes standard with my mac binary and requires no `library` call. See if it is installed. It works fine.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Saving a plot made with ggplot2 as an SVG is straightforward using the ggsave function.

However, additional package(s) beyond ggplot2 may be required, such as svglite.

Some sample code:

```
    require("ggplot2")
#some sample data
    head(diamonds) 
#to see actually what will be plotted and compare 
    qplot(clarity, data=diamonds, fill=cut, geom="bar")
#save the plot in a variable image to be able to export to svg
    image=qplot(clarity, data=diamonds, fill=cut, geom="bar")
#This actually save the plot in a image
    ggsave(file="test.svg", plot=image, width=10, height=8)
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Tried this today, got the error: `## Error in loadNamespace(name): there is no package called 'svglite'`. Installed and it works. Not sure why this was not installed along ggplot2.

Comment: If you get that message, just try this `install.packages('svglite')`

Comment: Is it better to use svglite, gridsvg or rvg ?

Comment: @alberto Downloading the package does not work. It throws this error: `ERROR: dependency ‘gdtools’ is not available for package ‘svglite’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/svglite’`

Comment: > ggsave(last_plot(), filename = "Cumulative Communities Reached by year (monotone).svg", width=6.0, height=6.0/1.5)
Error in match_family_(font, bold, italic) : 
  Fontconfig error: unable to match font pattern

Comment: You need `libcairo2-dev` on linux in order to compile `gdtools` which is needed by `svglite`.

Comment: This answer is misleading. `ggplot2` is **not** the only package required. As the comments state, `svglite` is also required.

Comment: I want to confirm I needed to install `libcairo2-dev` on linux first, then `install.packages('svglite')`, before this solution would work.

Comment: Have you ever had this error when saving in svg with ggplot?:

Error in grid.newpage() : svglite only supports one page

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the [save_plot](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/reference/save_plot.html) function from the `sjPlot` package. It is also possible to save the `ggplot` as the following file types: ".png", ".jpg", ".svg" or ".tif". Just replace the extension to whatever you want. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)
#> Install package "strengejacke" from GitHub (`devtools::install_github("strengejacke/strengejacke")`) to load all sj-packages at once!
p <- ggplot(diamonds,(aes(x = clarity, fill = cut))) +
  geom_bar()
p
```

[image]

```r
# save plot
save_plot("your_plot.svg", fig = p, width=10, height=8)
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The output of the saved plot:

[image]