# Keep italic font while exporting as SVG in R

Tags: r, svg, plot, ggplot2, inkscape

I am trying to export a figure as SVG from R to Inkscape (I am using RStudio 0.98.1102 and R version 3.1.2). Here is my script.

```
library(ggplot2)

Gene<-c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene1","Gene2")
count1<-c(12,14,16,34)
count2<-c(4,7,9,23)
count3<-c(36,22,54,12)
count4<-c(12,24,35,23)
Species<-c("A","A","B","B")
df<-data.frame(Gene,count1,count2,count3,count4,Species)

cols = c(2,3,4,5)
df1  = transform(df, mean=rowMeans(df[cols]), sd=apply(df[cols],1, sd))

# df1 looks like this
#   Gene count1 count2 count3 count4 Species  mean        sd
#1 Gene1     12      4     36     12       A 16.00 13.856406
#2 Gene2     14      7     22     24       A 16.75  7.804913
#3 Gene1     16      9     54     35       B 28.50 20.240224
#4 Gene2     34     23     12     23       B 23.00  8.981462

ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.factor(Gene), y=mean, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='black') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.8, size=14, colour="black",face="italic")
```

So, as you see, I want the x axis labels to be kept in italic font when exported to SVG... and they are not! ;-) They just come back to plain font.

I have tried the "classic" way, i.e. saving SVG directly with the plot interface in RStudio, and I have tried both ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226822/how-to-save-a-plot-made-with-ggplot2-as-svg), using whether `ggsave` or the `Cairo` package... None is working!

Any idea on what I should do?

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT:

What I have been able to do thanks to @baptiste comment:

1. Draw my plot with `ggplot2` and export it as SVG (with the legend not in italic) in `file1.svg`
2. Draw my plot with `gridSVG` in `file2.svg` using `grid.export("file2.svg")` (with error bars not displayed properly but with italic axis legend)
3. Modify `file2.svg` to keep only the italic axis legend and delete the other layers
4. Import the new `file2.svg` (italic axis legend only) into `file1.svg` using Inkscape, and adjust manually

Not elegant AT ALL, but working, though I would not like to do it for many files ;)
Hence I do not accept my edit as an answer!

Comment: maybe try the gridSVG package

Comment: @baptiste Mmmh... I just tried it (adding `grid.export("example.svg")` at the end of my script) and it's working indeed for the font, but I am not getting the error bars properly now! Maybe I should try another gridSVG function, or draw plot with another package?

Comment: I can get the correct output with `ggsave` to open in Firefox, but it looks a mess in Illustrator. Perhaps Inkscape doesn't interpret the italics correctly.