# how to ggsave() a grid.arranged plot as SVG

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I have code that produces two separate ggplots and combines them into a single figure using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

I can save this combined figure as a PNG using `ggsave()`, but if I try to save it as an SVG file, I get only the second figure. How can I get both figures in one SVG file?

**Edit**:
This question goes beyond that addressed in [How to save a plot made with ggplot2 as SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226822/how-to-save-a-plot-made-with-ggplot2-as-svg). `ggsave()` for SVG works well for single images, but DOES NOT WORK with SVG for images composed with `grid.arrange`.

Here is the figure I'm trying to create.  Code for this example is below.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
data(EastIndiesTrade,package="GDAdata")
c1 <- ggplot(EastIndiesTrade, aes(x=Year, y=Exports)) + 
             ylim(0,2000) + 
             geom_line(colour="black", size=2) + 
             geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=Imports), colour="red", size=2) +  
             geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Exports, ymax=Imports), fill="pink",alpha=0.5) + 
             ylab("Exports and Imports (millions of pounds)") +
             annotate("text", x = 1710, y = 0, label = "Exports", size=5) +
             annotate("text", x = 1770, y = 1620, label = "Imports", color="red", size=5) +
             annotate("text", x = 1732, y = 1950, label = "Balance of Trade to the East Indies", color="black", size=6) +             
             theme_bw()
c2 <- ggplot(EastIndiesTrade, aes(x=Year,
             y=Imports-Exports)) + geom_line(colour="blue", size=2) +
             ylab("Balance = Imports - Exports (millions of pounds)") +
             geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Imports-Exports, ymax=0), fill="pink",alpha=0.5) + 
             annotate("text", x = 1711, y = 30, label = "Our Deficit", color="black", size=6) +             
             theme_bw()

grid.arrange(c1, c2, nrow=1)
```

Now, I try to save them with `ggsave()`:

```
ggsave("east-indies-ggplot2.png", width=10, height=4)  # OK
ggsave("east-indies-ggplot2.svg", width=10, height=4)  # not OK -- only get the right panel
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a plot made with ggplot2 as SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226822/how-to-save-a-plot-made-with-ggplot2-as-svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably can try to use patchwork package

https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com
instead of grid.arrange

Then you need to just use

```
c3=c1+c2
ggsave("~/Desktop/plotdm.svg")
```

This worked for me

Best

Comment: For the record: gridExtra::grid.arrange was somewhat of a kludge.  `patchwork` is the way to go for this in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you put the grid.arrange call into the ggsave function as follows:

```
ggsave("east-indies-ggplot2.svg", plot = grid.arrange(c1, c2, nrow=1), width=10, height=4)
```

It will call grid.arrange and simultaneously save the svg.