# How to get SVG string from R ggplot image?

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg

In R, suppose I have a `ggplot` object like `p` below from a tutorial:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(
        day = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
        value = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000
)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=day, y=value)) +
        geom_line() +
        xlab("")
```

I don't want to see the image, and I don't want to save it to a file. What I would like is to get a string that is the SVG for this image without doing either of those things. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to have an intermediary step and save it to a temporary file, there are many "convert ggplot to svg" questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226822/how-to-save-a-plot-made-with-ggplot2-as-svg and svglite https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/svglite-2-0-0/

Comment: can you work with https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gridSVG/html/grid.export.html

Comment: @user20650 this works, too, just tested, please post as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `svglite::svgstring()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(svglite)

data <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  value = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000
)

s <- svgstring()

ggplot(data, aes(x=day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("")

my_svg <- s()
dev.off()
```

Where `my_svg` is a string containing:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' class='svglite' width='720.00pt' height='576.00pt' viewBox='0 0 720.00 576.00'>
<defs>
  <style type='text/css'><![CDATA[
    .svglite line, .svglite polyline, .svglite polygon, .svglite path, .svglite rect, .svglite circle {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10.00;
    }
    .svglite text {
      white-space: pre;
    }
  ]]></style>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was hoping existed.

Comment: Just a note for future readers that I needed to wrap the `ggplot` in `plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
graph_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
on.exit(unlink(graph_file), add = TRUE)

png(filename = graph_file,
    width = 500, height = 500, units = "px", 
    bg = "white",  
    res = NA, 
)

p
dev.off()

readBin(graph_file, "raw", n=file.info(graph_file)$size) |> 
    intToUtf8()
```

Comment: `"I don't want to save it to a file"`

Comment: @zx8754 Without saving it to file you cannot get the contents of png

Comment: I'd go with your solution, too, but the op doesn't want to save.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it is true I don't want to save to file. This is for an application with many users and I want to avoid all the disk IO if files were written to disk.